# Oracle and SQL Server `CEIL/CEILING` functions return different results

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ceil

In Oracle:

- Input: `Select CEIL(5.416579) From Dual`
- Output: 5.42

In SQL Server:

- Input: `Select CEILING(5.416579)`
- Output: 6

As per Oracle and SQL Server `CEIL/CEILING` functions return an integer value, but here both of them return different results.

Comment: Can you clarify the Oracle DB version that you are using, as I am unable to reproduce your observation on `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production`?

Comment: Oracle 18 returns 6: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7719b1a4a61ddd1b7a7eaafefb27a25a

Comment: The [Oracle `CEIL` Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions017.htm#SQLRF00614) states "`CEIL(n)` returns smallest integer greater than or equal to `n`." So `CEIL(5.416579)` will return `6`.

Answer (score 0):

The [Oracle `CEIL` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions017.htm#SQLRF00614) states:

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> CEIL(n)
> ```
>
> **Purpose**
>
> `CEIL` returns smallest integer greater than or equal to `n`.

So `CEIL(5.416579)` function will always return `6` in Oracle.

The only way I can see for you to get a different result is if someone has create a user-defined `CEIL` function in your schema and that is being invoked rather than the built-in function:

*(Don't do this)*

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION SCHEMA_NAME.CEIL(n NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER
AS
  i INTEGER := TRUNC( n * 100 );
BEGIN
  IF i <> n * 100 THEN
    RETURN (i + 1)/100;
  ELSE
    RETURN i/100;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

But even then, `SELECT CEIL(5.416579) FROM DUAL` appears to use the global built-in function and returns `6`. To override this you have to explicitly state the package:

```sql
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME.CEIL(5.416579) FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> ```
> 5.42
> ```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=39818624b6d0999937fb09514a37fb51)

Check you don't have another function called `CEIL` but without that, the behaviour you are describing should be impossible.

Answer (score -1):

The precision setting has most likely changed to a minimum precision of 2 on your system.